# After dropdown selection, store selection and refresh same page with the result from mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a drop down list that is populated by the database (the students first name and surname). This works fine. There is some javascript which allows the search to work but its not relevant to my question. The code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Find person ></button>
      <div id="Dropdown" class="drop-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" id="myInput"
```

The idea is for the user to select a person from the dropdown list and then for the information about that student to be output on the same page as the dropdown (so no page reload). At the moment it just doesn't do anything, no error showing either.

Comment: Can you tell us what are you getting as the `response` from `output.php` ?

Comment: Im getting no response at the moment, when I click nothing is happening

Comment: I mean when you do `console.log(response)` what does the output come as ? - `undefined` or blank line in your console

Comment: I think this is what youre talking about 'ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Comment: Which means JQuery library itself is not loaded. Can you check if you have included the JQuery library in your html. Meaning the backend call is not even been made in the first place.

Comment: ive started my script with the following '<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js">' but it says 404 not found?

Comment: it has **two** `src` attribute ? Remove `src="javascript/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"` if not needed

Comment: sorry im getting this 'ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined'

Comment: You need `jquery` **not just** `jquery-ui`. Use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Okay thats working then, but still nothing

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would get started:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Find Student ></button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
        <div id="studentdrop">
            <?php
            // $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=thename', 'root', 'root');
            // $result = $pdo->query('SELECT student_forename, student_surname FROM students');
            $result = array(
                array("student_id" => 1, "student_forename" => 'Joe', "student_surname" => 'Jones'),
                array("student_id" => 2, "student_forename" => 'Mary', "student_surname" => 'Jones'),
                array("student_id" => 3, "student_forename" => 'Perry', "student_surname" => 'Wallace')
            );
            echo "<select id='user_id'>";
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                echo '<option value="' . $row['student_id'] . '">' . $row['student_forename'] . " " . $row['student_surname'] . '</option>';
            }
            echo "</select>";
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="data"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.dropbtn').click(function () {
            $.get( "output.php", { id: $('#user_id option:selected').val() }, function(data) {
                $('.data').text(data);
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

That will be the page that pulls from the database and setups up the select with the options. You will have to modify since I did not have time to setup the db and test it out. But the result is an array that can be used with the select options.

I also update the javascript to make the get request to pull the user data and populate a `<div>`tag with the data returned.

Here is the `output.php` page:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
switch($id) {
    case 1:
        echo "This is student Joe Jones";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "This is student Mary Jones";
        break;
    case 3:
        echo "This is student Perry Wallace";
        break;
}
```

This is a simple page, but you can modify it to query the database and return any data that you want. This is using the passed in `id` from the the ajax get request from the `index.php` page. I would recommend adding input validation and checks to make sure it is sanitized data.

If you create a directory and place these 2 files in there you can run it with the **PHP** built in server. Here is what I like to do: `php -S localhost:8080`.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

The Flow -

Dropdown Change by User -> Function in JS triggered -> Call to PHP file with  and return the Response -> Get the response in the JS Function -> Update your DOM.

Now you must create the `output.php` in the same directory your other files are (you may change later on based on your structure), now in your JS function you are not passing anything to the php file - you need to pass the SELECTED data.

**JS Edit:**
Pass the data in JSON format if using POST or in URL if using GET.

**PHP Edit:**
Decode the JSON data in $_POST['var_name'] or Directly access get parameters using $_GET['var_name'].

That should work ... let me know if anything.